# RIS in SISO system

Tags: matlab

RIS system with 1. antenna receiver and 1.antenna transmitter

I want to write a MATLAB code for channel estimation using the ls method in a RIS system and I need a simple and basic code to start working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately this type of request is not on-topic for stackoverflow. Try something and come back when you have issues.